# Is there a function to randomize the volumes of a MIDI Clip on Ableton Live?

Tags: ableton-live, volume, random

I'd like to know if there is a function to randomize the volumes of a MIDI Clip on Ableton Live in order to simulate a human playing. I can do it manually (It's what I do all the time), but as you can see, I'm quite lazy about it and that's why I'm asking if there is such a function in the first place. The difference between the volumes must be small, since a great one could sound as inhuman as the flat default one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a “Velocity” MIDI effect in Ableton Live, with a patch called “Add some random.” Place this MIDI effect onto the channel that you want to randomize.